# Sort python list by function

Tags: python, list, function, sorting

I have a function that takes an object as an argument and gives me a number. I wish to use this number as the key to sort my list.

If I were to iterate over the list I would do something like:

```py
sorted_list = []
for object in my_list_of_objects:
    i = my_number_giving_function(object)
    sorted_list.insert(i, object)
```

How can I use `sorted` to get the same result? This is what I came up with but I don't know what to put in the '???'.

```py
sorted_list = sorted(my_list_of_objects, key=my_number_giving_function(???))
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
sort(my_list_of_objects, key=my_number_giving_function)
```

same for sorted, [see the Python Sorting HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/sorting.html)

Comment: Hah, I guess I don't need the lambda part.  I didn't think that through.

Comment: if `func` takes exactly one argument, then `func` is equivalent to `lambda x: func(x)`. This is known as eta-reduction.

Answer (score 1):

A lambda function is useful if your sorting function takes a support argument, otherwise function name is enough. For example, if you want to sort list of string representation of datetime by date, then passing the format is necessary.

```py
from datetime import datetime
sorted_list = sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y')) # sorted new list

# or call sort() on the list for inplace sorting
my_list.sort(key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y'))                  # old list is sorted
```