# Sorting functions in a list

Tags: python, sorting

I'm learning Python and I wanted some more information on how to sort lists. I know there's a lot on sorting strings in lists and lists in lists and integers in lists and on and on, but what I want to know is how to sort *objects* in lists (and it would probably help in other languages). Like, say I have this:

```
import random

class Example()
    def __init__(self):
        self.choose_if_special = randint(0,10)
        self.special = None
    def see_if_special(self):
        """determines if it is special"""
        if self.choose_if_special == 3:
           self.special = True
        else:
           self.special = False

list = []
max_examples = 10
for i in range(0, max_examples):
    #pushes max_examples Example(s) to list list
    list.append(Example())
for j in list:
    #prints not sorted list
    print(j)
```

But what if I wanted all the functions with `.special = True` printed first, or last? Is there a specific function that can do this? Or do you have to do something else? I've thought up and viewed some possible solutions, but just to make sure I'm not wasting my time is there a function that does this in Python or in one of its libraries? And if not what is the quickest and most effective way to sort the list (so it doesn't run slower)?

Comment: Where do you actually attempt to sort the list? Have you tried using `sorted` or `sort` with a key argument?

Comment: have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135836/sort-python-list-by-function

Comment: Everything in Python is an object, so when you do your **regular integer sort**, you actually sort objects like in this case. You just need to find out how two connects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In summary, you can use the builtin functions: `sort` or `sorted`. The difference is that, using `sort` you will change your original list, while using `sorted` will not.

First, you need to set accordingly your **special** value for each of your list Example object:

```
for example in list:
    example.see_if_special()
```

After that, you can do a `sort` on your list:

```
list.sort(key=lambda example: int(example.special), reverse=True)
```

Or generate a new list without modifying your original list:

```
sorted(list, key=lambda example: int(example.special), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

From a quick google I found Python has a function called sorted which can be used in a situation like this. In your case:

```
sorted_objects = sorted(list_of_objects, key=lambda object: object.special, reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement an ordering (that will not change) in your own class, define `__lt__` (for the `<` operator), `__lte__` (for the `<=` operator), `__gt__` for the `>` operator and `__gte__` (for the `>=` operator). `j.sort` or `sorted(j)` will automatically use the ordering you defined to sort the list.

If you want to sort in a way that will not be the same throughout your code, use the named argument `key=some_function` (for both `list.sort` and `sorted`). The `key` function is given an element of the list and the result of this function will be used to decide how it is sorted. For example:

```
for e in list:
    e.see_if_special()

for e in sorted(list, key=lambda x: x.special):
    print(e)
```

will first print all elements that have `.special == False` and then the ones for which `.special == True`.