# Sorting a dictionary alphabetically regardless of capitalization

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary that basically matches a number to a character, e.g.  `foo = {'z':1, 'A':1, 'a':1, 'b':3}`. The dictionary is currently completely randomized both numerically and alphabetically, however I do know how to sort is numerically, but I currently just want sort the characters alphabetically regardless of capitalization. So far I have tried using `sortednames=sorted(foo.keys(), key=lambda x:x.lower())` but that returns a list of the sorted characters and now the matching numbers are gone. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Can you post what you've attempted so far?

Comment: Ok, so technically I take in the dictionary completely unsorted by number and alphabetically. So far I have just sorted it numberically using: 
sorted_tuples = sorted(foo.items(), key = operator.itemgetter(1))
sorted_foo = {k: v for k, v in sorted_tuples}
Where foo is my original completely unsorted dictionary. Now I am thinking maybe if I can first sort it alphabetically then I can use the previous code and then sort it numerically after I have sorted it alphabetically.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Do these answer your question? [How do I do a case-insensitive string comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319426/how-do-i-do-a-case-insensitive-string-comparison), [Sort python list by function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7135836/4518341), [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/613183/4518341), and [Sorting a dictionary by value then key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9919342/4518341)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour]. There are like 4 different aspects to this question, and it seems like you've only tackled a few, so I recommended some existing questions that cover the other parts. BTW, note that in older versions of Python, dicts are unordered.

Answer (score 2):

Same as Gerges' answer, but you did say that you still wanted your dictionary numerically sorted, so just a slight modification to the original answer:

```
d = {'z':1, 'A':1, 'a':1, 'b':3}

dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0].lower())))

# {'A': 1, 'a': 1, 'z': 1, 'b': 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care if things are copied around, you can try this:

```
d = {'z':1, 'A':1, 'a':1, 'b':3}

dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[0].lower()))

# {'A': 1, 'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'z': 1}
```

Comment: This is good, but it breaks the numeric sort