# Sorting python3 list by a value returned from a function that takes two arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

Referring to this: [Sort python list by function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135836/sort-python-list-by-function)

in my case my function takes two arguments:

problem:

```
sorted_list = sorted(my_list_of_objects, key=my_number_giving_function(???,y))
```

Given solution:

```
sort(my_list_of_objects, key=my_number_giving_function)
```

Code I tried:

```
sorted_list = sorted(my_list_of_objects, key=my_number_giving_function(y))
```

Error: missing 1 required positional argument: y

Solution: Use a lambda. key=lambda x: my_number_giving_function(x, y)

Comment: You don't pass anything into the function, `sort()` will do that. The `key` argument is the function, not a call to the function. Remove the `()`.

Comment: id.sort(reverse=True)

Comment: @Will that will give `[3, 2, 1]`, not `[2, 3, 1]`. OP wants to sort by the return value of the function. You need that function as the key.

Comment: @MattDMo what you mean with OP?

Comment: @Will Original Poster. The person who posted the question.

Comment: @Barmar can you explain how I'd pass a second argument to the function?

Comment: Use a `lambda`. `key=lambda x: my_number_giving_function(x, y)`

Comment: @DevTTW: `functools.partial`. Or a simple wrapper `lambda` function that takes one argument and passes the other for you. The latter is a basic programming skill, writing a function that can call another function with different arguments. The former is a more niche tool that people not from a functional programming background might not be aware of.